# join two pivot tables

Tags: join, pivot

I have two queries in MS SQL Server 2012 :

```
**Query for Uploads:**    
select Contract_Code, [201612] as '201612',[201701] as '201701', [201702] as '201702' from (select OrderID, Creation_Date_YYYYMM, Contract_Code from Raw_Data_A) p
    pivot(count(OrderID) for Creation_Date_YYYYMM in ([201612],[201701],[201702])) as pvt
    order by Contract_Code


**Query for REal Orders:**    
select Contract_Code, [201612] as '201612',[201701] as '201701', [201702] as '201702' from (select OrderID, concat(year([Creation_Date]),format([Creation_date],'MM')) as Creation_Date_YYYYMM, Contract_Code from Raw_Data_B) p2
    pivot(count(OrderID) for Creation_Date_YYYYMM in ([201612],[201701],[201702])) as pvt
    order by Contract_Code
```

that each produce results like:

```
Contract_Code   201612  201701  201702
Contract1   3   1   0
Contract2   17  0   6
Contract3   23  8   14
Contract4   48  45  6
```

I would like to join them in order to achieve the following output:

```
             201612     201701  201702  
ContractNameRealUploadRealUploadRealUpload
Contract1   23  24  35  26  27  28
Contract2   24  45  36  26  27  28
Contract3   25  45  37  26  27  28
Contract4   26  45  38  26  27  28
Contract5   27  45  39  26  27  28
Contract6   28  45  40  26  27  28
Contract7   29  45  41  26  27  28
Contract8   30  45  42  26  27  28
Contract9   31  45  43  26  27  28
Contract10  32  45  44  26  27  28
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with the following code:

```
select coalesce(a.Contract_Code,b.Contract_Code),b.[201612],a.[201612],b.[201701],a.[201701],b.[201702],a.[201702] from

(select Contract_Code, [201612] as '201612',[201701] as '201701', [201702] as '201702' from (select OrderID, Creation_Date_YYYYMM, Contract_Code from Raw_Data_A) as b
pivot(count(OrderID) for Creation_Date_YYYYMM in ([201612],[201701],[201702])) as pvt) a


full join

(select Contract_Code, [201612] as '201612',[201701] as '201701', [201702] as '201702' from (select OrderID, concat(year([Creation_Date]),format([Creation_date],'MM')) as Creation_Date_YYYYMM, Contract_Code from Raw_Data_B) as b
pivot(count(OrderID) for Creation_Date_YYYYMM in ([201612],[201701],[201702])) as pvt) b

on a.Contract_Code=b.Contract_Code
order by coalesce(a.Contract_Code,b.Contract_Code);
```